# How to use AWS Cognito SDK to authenticate user from REST Service using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-cognito

all!

I am currently facing a problem to authenticate users from my Cognito UserPool using a lambda function built using ClaudiaJS+Claudia-API-Builder and exposed on API Gateway through "/api/auth". I can't seem to find a way to succeed on calling the `cognitoUser.authenticateUser`.

All the resources I've found so far are for calling this API via Browser, but I couldn't find any example of doing so on backend.

I've already tried to deal with the response as a regular callback, promises and object listeners, but none of them seemed to work and I always end up getting a {"message": "Internal server error"} message as response from my REST service.

It's also important to say that I'am fairly new to Node and Async programming, but would you mind please reviewing this piece of code and telling me the correct way to do so, IF this SDK was designed to be invoked from backend instead of frontend?

My App.js

```
var ApiBuilder = require('claudia-api-builder');
var api = new ApiBuilder();

//Routes
var usuario = require('./routes/usuario');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');

//Caminho default da API
var API_ROOT = "simc/api";
//User Routes
api.get(API_ROOT + "/f1", usuario.f1);
api.get(API_ROOT + "/f2", usuario.f2);

//Auth Routes
api.get(API_ROOT + "/login", auth.login);
module.exports = api;
```

My auth route

```
"use strict"
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var AWSCognito = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

var authAPI = {};


authAPI.login = function() {
     var authenticationData = {
          Username: 'xxxxxx',
          Password: 'xxxxxx',
     };
     var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
     var poolData = {
          UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_xxxxxx',
          ClientId: 'xxxxxx'
     };


     var userPool = new AWSCognito.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
     var userData = {
          Username: 'xxxxxx',
          Pool: userPool
     };

     //Trying to use Promises
     var cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoUser(userData);
     return cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails)
          .then(function(result) {
               console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
               //Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer
               console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
               return result;
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
               console.log(err);
               return err;
          });

     //Trying to use Object Listeners
     var request = cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails).promise();
     return request.on('success', function(response) {
          console.log('access token + ' + response.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
          //Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer
          console.log('idToken + ' + response.idToken.jwtToken);
          return response;
     }).
     on('failure', function(err) {
          console.log("Error!");
          return err;
     }).send();

};


module.exports = authAPI;
```

I have modified the original handler because it also doesn't seem to work properly.

```
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
            /*Use the idToken for Logins Map when Federating User Pools with Cognito Identity or when passing through an Authorization Header to an API Gateway Authorizer*/
            console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
            return 'idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken;
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            return err;//alert(err);
        },

    });
```

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Enrico Bergamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var authenticationDetails = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
```

Use this one to include the function.